# AWS DMS Kafka target endpoint testing failed showing "application error 1020912: failed to connect to database"

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-dms, aws-msk

I created a DMS instance in a public subnet without public access. Kafka is created as an MSK cluster in a private subnet, within the same VPC. No SSL.

Endpoint testing shows application error 1020912: failed to connect to database.

I can confirm that Kafka is running fine, and I can list topics via a bastion host in the same subnet as the DMS instance.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the console and [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kafka.html) are misleading stating that topic is optional. The topic is compulsory and must exist when testing the connection.

Adding `auto.create.topics.enable = true` does not work for testing connections.

Comment: Indeed. I was having the same problem and solved by creating the topic manually.